# Duplication of value in array in state

Tags: reactjs

**My problem**

I'm trying to add a component to an array at the input of a user(here the Building component).
My problem is that everything i add in this array is somehow duplicated and i can't explain it.
I also wasn't able to reproduce the problem in codesandbox but here is my town component that adds new Building components :
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-bhabha-yb6sq

The problem lies in the function addBuilding, because the position is added there and the duplicate does not contain the same position as the prévious building.
I've also made sure that the function is not called two times, à console.log inside the function told me that.

In this function i :

1. Copy the object i receive from a parent component (props.addBuild).
2. Create à new position .
3. add the position to the copy of the object.
4. give it a key number.
5. add it to the set.
6. done.

*What happens :*

I made sure there is no other push nowhere else (i've commented this function and nothing showed up as i triggered the addition of a new building)
As the component re-renders the duplication occurs.

**What i've tried so far**

1. I've tried using set instead of arrays which gives me the same
   result.
2. I've also tried to copy the state and use the setState at the end which resulted in a too much calls of setState.
3. Pop the entire content of my state and push back the once that i want to keep.
4. I've also tried to add the function somewhere else in my program and got the same results.

A thing that would be a bit trashy but could solve my problem would be to remove duplicates from the array or set and add them back in the array. I've tried this and got too much calls to render error. But i'm sure there might be a way i have not tried.

Another detail is that i'm using electron.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You change state which will cause a rerender, which will cause to add another building. Controlling internal state from external component is just a bad idea. Move the state up.
You are essentially changing your state from `render`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean to move it to the parent component? I've already tried to move it to the parent component and i've got the same result unforunately. But your comment is interesting, i'll take note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by moving up my code in the parent component like suggested by @Sulthan.
But also instead of using a state i used a function so instead of passing a state as a prop to the town component i directly called the function that added a building to the list of building.

Here is what it looks like :
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-bhabha-yb6sq?file=/src/App.js

I still can't explain what happened but the state that called the function addBuilding provoked a second call of this function.